# Google like search using DevExpress LookUpEdit

Tags: devexpress

We need to implement google like search functionality using DevExpress lookup edit control.

Please let me know If anyone implemented similar control.

Thanks
Apple

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your task properly, this kind of filtering is supported by the LookupEdit by default.  Please run the EditorsProperties demo and check how the lookup works.

Answer (score 0):

For this kind of task the lookupedit control doesn't suit.